What is the exact reasoning behind integrating both sides of an equation with bounds?
Say I have an equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2y$$ where $y = 1$ when $x = 0$.
Rearrange:
$$dy=2ydx$$
Integrate:
$$\int^y_1 dy=\int^x_0 2ydx$$
My question is why can we do this last step. I don't see the precise logic why we can set these bounds and strictly say that they are equal.
There are also questions where we set the lower bound to be the state of the variable before and the upper bound to be the state of the variable after. Could someone also explain the logic behind this.

We have $y’=2y$, so we can integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$ to get
\begin{align}
\int_0^xy’(s)\,ds&=\int_0^x2y(s)\,ds.
\end{align}
Now, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus on the LHS:
\begin{align}
y(x)-y(0)&=\int_0^x2y(s)\,ds,
\end{align}
and finally use the assumption $y(0)=1$ to get
\begin{align}
y(x)-1&=\int_0^x2y(s)\,ds.
\end{align}
It is this final equation which has been abbreviated into $\int_1^y\,dy=\int_0^x2y\,dx$… which I actually abhor since it uses the same letter as the integration variable and the limit of integration. See this for some more remarks about dummy variables in integrals.
